# Filter oModel on read

Tags: sapui5, hana

I'm trying to filter data from model, this is my code:

```
    onInit: function() {
    var self=this;
    var oFilters = [  ];
    oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(
        "/SapTest/services/persons.xsodata",false);


    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table; 
    oTable = self.byId("persons");
    console.log(oTable);

    var filters = new Array();  
    var filterByName = new sap.ui.model.Filter("NAME", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, "claudio")  
    filters.push(filterByName);  

    oModelJson = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.read("/persons",null,null,null,function(oData,oResponse){
        oModelJson.setData(oData);
    },null);
    oTable.setModel(oModelJson);
    console.log(oModelJson);
}
```

How can I apply the created filters directly to the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of position-wise parameter you'd better use object parameter, the source would be more readable:

```
(...)
oModel.read("/persons", {
             filters: filters,
             success: function(oData,oResponse){
                         oModelJson.setData(oData);
                      }
            });
(...)
```

for more details refer [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read)